# how to validate only files are pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to create a regular expression in a FileUpload,
that only allow pdf files

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="valUpTest" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
                           ErrorMessage="Files Only (.pdf)" ValidationExpression="?" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942830/problem-validating-filetypes-in-an-asp-net-fileupload-control-with-regularexpress

Comment: Why would you use a regex? A simple string.EndsWith is clean and simple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131430.aspx

Comment: In addition to validating the filename extension you should also validate the file contents itself, i.e. check if they contain certain magic bytes. This prevents the user from simply renaming the file to fool your filter.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

There is an example about 3/4 of the way down the page how to do this the ASP way.

Comment: While it doesn't prevent users from spoofing the filter, this is the simplest way (and most verbose for the user).

Answer (score 1):

You cant trust client side validation alone nor file extension. You need to open the uploaded binary data and check if the headers of the file is "correct".

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\.pdf$
```